# C# Type.GetFields different orders based on environment

Tags: c#, types, enums

Say you have an enum like the following:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public enum Colors
    {
        Red = 0,
        Blue = 1,
        Green = 2,
        Yellow = 3
    }
}
```

You want to retrieve the enum as an array, so you use this function to get all the information and then send it back to the front end.

```
Type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
```

where type is my enum Colors. Now in my local environment, I get the values in the ordered they're declared. Every time I refresh the page the enum array is ordered the same, no changes.

However, my app is already deployed in another environment, and in this server is retrieving the array in different ordered every time.  This is causing a front end error but I can't fix something I can't actually see on my local environment.

Does the Type.GetFields function has a different behavior regarding, I don't know, the .NET Framework version I'm using to run the project? That's the only thing I can think of at the moment.

I need to reproduce this in my environments before making this change.

Comment: @GSerg not particularly. Because I need to reproduce the array being randomly ordered in my local environment before making this change. On other environments (clients) the array is being randomly ordered. In my dev environments the order is the same every time. Same code for all environments

Comment: If you need a particular order, then order it. If you are relying on this order then you are ignoring the advice of the documentation. As to why the order is different, its likely an optimization thing, or any other number of quirks..

Comment: I always use `Enum.GetNames()` for that.  If I remember correctly, it does return them in the *expected* order.  Actually, the **Remarks** say *The elements of the return value array are sorted by the binary values of the enumerated constants (that is, by their unsigned magnitude).*

Answer (score 1):

From the [`Type.GetFields()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfields?view=netcore-3.1):

> ### Remarks
>
> The GetFields method does not return fields in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. **Your code must not depend on the order in which fields are returned**, because that order varies.

Comment: I already saw that and looks pretty straightforward to me. However, why in my dev environments I'm getting the order just fine whereas in other environments (clients) the order changes every time is being requested?

Comment: @ggderas Since you saw it, and you thought it was straightforward, why ask the question that is is the straightforward answer to?

Comment: @Servy My question is about trying to understand, based on what the items are being ordered NOT if they're being ordered at all. Because like I explained above, in some environments the order is the exact same order every time whereas in other environments is random every time. What is it that make certain env work differently? That's my question

Comment: @ggderas I get that you want to understand what's going on, but I think you're looking at it the wrong way as this is a really low-level detail that we, as consumers of .NET, shouldn't _have_ to understand. By not just ordering the collection yourself, any workaround you come up with may stop working at some other point in time, and the fact it "works" in one environment but not another proves that you could run into the same problem again if your environment subsequently changes for whatever reason in the future. Make it deterministic and the problem goes away.

Comment: @JohnH yes, you're right. I probably need to do that change. It just before doing any changes I need to proof that it isn't working on our environments so I can report the bug and treat it as needed. But yeah. I'll probably end up doing what you suggested. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Enum.GetNames()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getnames) instead of `Type.GetFields()`.

The **Remarks** for that method say:

> The elements of the return value array are sorted by the binary values of the enumerated constants (that is, by their unsigned magnitude).

It's specified in the documentation, so it should be consistent.

Comment: Now I'm curious. Perhaps someone down voted me because the title asked about `Type.GetFields`. However, the body of the question started *"Say you have an enum...[and] You want to retrieve the enum as an array"*. The OP was asking about getting information from an enum to pass to a different layer in a consistent fashion. This answer does that. Oh well.